# Django Redirect URL

Tags: python, django, httpresponse

I am new to Django, and i am now trying to use the `HttpResponseRedirect()` function. But I am so confused that if I use it like `HttpResponseRedirect('good/')`, and the current page is `'/bad/'`, it can only be redirected to `'/bad/good/'`, which is an url of current page appended with the url value from the `HttpResponseRedirect()` function. I tried to search google, and could not find any solution.

How can I redirect to the page with specific url? For example, `HttpResponseRedirect('/good/')` to `/good/` rather than `/bad/good/` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surely you must see that there's a difference between `'good/'` and `'/good/'`? The former will always add itself onto the existing page, whereas the latter will start from the root. This is basic web behaviour, and nothing to do with Django.

In any case, you should never hard-code URLs like that, but should use Django's [URL-reversing functionality](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls) to calculate the URLs dynamically.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, that works. And thanks for your suggestion on Revering functions. I will try to learn and modify my code with Reverse(). :)

Comment: I would not say that this is *basic web behaviour* since appending to current URL is not a part of any HTTP specification (purely browser dependent). Thus paths not starting with protocol or `/` should be avoided at all costs.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to redirect to urls in your domain, you can use [**redirect**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect). You can use redirect to view with by using patterns in your urls.py file or to any urls you 'd like. Although I strongly encourage the usage of views as indicates the different tutorials available on their website.

Better check out django documentation that is one of the most complete out there (to my humble opinion)

/edit for lack of clarity indeed.

Comment: -1: That's absolutely not true. You can redirect to **any** URL, even outside your domain (also strictly speaking every URL inside domain is handled by Django, it's only that those not defined result in 404). Also HTTP/1.0 specification clearly states that URLs should be given in **absolute** form (HTTP/1.1 allows relative though). Besides it does not answer the question.

Comment: The OP wants obviously to redirect to his domain, better do it as the documentation proposes to. with reverse urls.

Comment: That's not obvious at all. Besides it doesn't matter. You still stated something that is not true: you can redirect to any url, even if there is no handler. I'm not saying that what documentation proposes is wrong. I'm saying that you are not telling the truth.